# div doesn't position itself below bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap's navbar css. Below this navbar I have a  which I want to put below the navbar. However, why does it always start at the top and not below the navbar? I've looked at twitter bootstrap's example and they were able to have a  positioned below the fixed navbar. Here's the link to my [website](http://directory.shopious.com). Any idea why this is?

Here's the html that I have now:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
</div>

<section id="main">

</section>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The `fixed navbar` will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   `padding` to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use
>   our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> ```
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
> ```
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

ref: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

I dont know why they dont put this note in bootstrap 2.3.2 but this is what you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I fix my navbar and set the container as following

```
.maincontainer{ padding-top: 75px; }
```

75 pixel is enough and doesn't affect Bootstrap on Responsive design in Tablet and Mobile. Work perfect everywhere :)